# Probability given A & B are independent.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $P(A) = 0.4$ and $P(A \cap B) = 0.3$. If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then find the following:

(a) $P(B)$

(b) $P(A\cup B) $

(c) $P(A \cap \bar{B})$

Are $A$ and $\bar{B}$ independent?

I know $P(B) = 0.75$ and $P(A\cup B) = 0.85$. I just need help with $P(A\cap\bar{B}) $

$P(\bar{B}) = 1 - P(B) = 0.25$

Comment: We are not here to blindly answer your homework questions. Please show what you have already done towards solving this problem. If you truly cannot get started, then write down the definitions and techniques you have been taught about to solve similar problems and we will be able to help you get started at the right level of knowledge

Comment: I did I wrote down the first two answers.. I don't know how to find out P(A & Bcomplement)...

Comment: So edit your question and add details such as what you understand the definition of $B$ complement to be

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

[If $A$ and $B$ are independent that implies that $Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

[In every case, we have that $Pr(A\cup B) = Pr(A)+Pr(B)-Pr(A\cap B)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

[In every case, we have that $Pr(A) = Pr(A\cap B) + Pr(A\cap B^c)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

Comment: So, P(A and Bcomplement) = .1 and they are independent since .25*.4 = .1.

Comment: @KawaiiGirl420 Yes. Btw it can be proved that independence of events $A,B$ implies independence of $E,F$ whenever $E\in\{A,A^{\complement}\}$ and $F\in\{B,B^{\complement}\}$